# Visual Studio 2012: Different branch symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, icons

When I branch a solution while connected to the cloud-version of the TFS a different icon is displayed for my branches

[image: this little icon that looks like a mini flow-chart]

When I am connect to the on-premise version only the folder-symbol is used.

So my question is: Does the icon depend on the TFS-version of did I make a mistake in the on-premise version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use same version of visual studio/team explorer? I would say you made a mistake. locally i use vs2013 and tfs 2010 and it still shows the branch symbols on branches.

To verify you can right click on your folder that you think is a branch, and select Branching and Merging. If you have the option "Convert to branch" it is definately a folder. On branches you will have the option "Convert to folder" and "Reparent".
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm I do not have the option "Convert to folder" or "Convert to branch". I have this options when using the tfs-could version. Could this be a permission problem?

Comment: I don't have any special permissions on my server, so I don't think so. I'll add a screendump to my answer.

Comment: I just found this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx and there I found this "The release of Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 began a distinction between branches and folders. The following illustration shows the top-level of the DinnerNow folder structure..." So I assume our on-premise TFS is the version 2008.

Comment: Ah, there you have it. You should probably start lobbying for an upgrade then.

Comment: Yes definitely, but the TFS hosting is not in my domain. Thank you for your help!